# How get result of CoreData expression query without error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

## Overview:

I am trying to learn how to fetch certain statistical properties from a Core Data store (e.g. sum, avg, min, max). I have been successful retrieving an average to a dictionary with the following code, but I have to get the results as a dictionary.

## Goal:

Ideally, I'd like to get the result along with the full results of the query by extending the custom managed objects class "Contact" that was autogenerated by Xcode Core Data managed object model. So far I have been unsuccessful. I get similar errors no matter what I try.

## Error:

```
NSManagedObjectResultType not compatible with contents of propertiesToFetch'or similar
```

## Code:

```
func avgdemoFloat()->Float{
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let result:Float = 0
do{

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Contact")
    let keypathExp = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "demoFloat") 
    let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "average:", arguments: [keypathExp])
    let avg = NSExpressionDescription()
    avg.expression = expression
    avg.name = "avg"
    avg.expressionResultType = .floatAttributeType

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.propertiesToFetch = [avg]

    let results = try context.fetch(request)
    print(results)
}
```

I'm not experienced enough to sort this out. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand the question, do you want to find the average of a particular field ?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the average for 'demofloat', a Float, but this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the `propertiesToFetch` the `resultType` needs to be set as shown below:

```
request.resultType = . dictionaryResultType
```